# Google Calendar API: Requests from referer http://localhost are blocked

Tags: api, localhost, google-calendar-api

I am trying to call the Google Calendar API on my local.
But I am getting error.

```
{message: "Requests from referer http://localhost/ are blocked.", domain: "global", reason: "forbidden"}
```

If anyone has ever faced, please help me.

Comment: Can you check if your API credentials for Google Calendar API is restricted or not?

Comment: Well.. i think it isn't reason of it. it is working on domain

Comment: I assume this is a JS app? Have you added your localhost with port number to the whitelisted origins when setting up your credentials?